# syntax error /shell/indexer.php

Tags: magento-1.9, indexer

I can not make my magento reindexing it gives me this error:

X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

**Parse error**:  `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in` **/home/Darlin/www/shell/indexer.php** on line **43**

I connect in SSH via the terminal utility (mac)

Comment: What's the script look like around line 43 there (for example, lines 35-50)?

Comment: Line 43
protected function _getIndexer()
    {
        return $this->_factory->getSingleton($this->_factory->getIndexClassAlias());
    }

Comment: Am I not mistaken? You are trying to run magento on php v.4.4.9 ?

Comment: Yes. I want to re-index. The version of my php to a problem?

Comment: https://magento.com/resources/system-requirements better use php 5.4 or 5.5

Comment: In what file should be put php 5.5?

Comment: Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.
The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:

    You need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)

The following requirements were successfully met:

    You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server setups specifically and not about Magento. The user needs to figure out how to setup a server correctly before even attempting to setup Magento.

Comment: Hello, I contact my host it told me that my php are up to date. It me contact in the day to tell me more about the problem. Everything is updated my my ssh always gives me 4.4.9

Comment: The problem is resolved the problem came from Simple configurable product

Answer (score 1):

Update your PHP to 5.3 or Magento will not work.

Comment: How to update php?

Comment: Contact your server administer. PHP 4.4.9 came out in 2008. You might as well get a new server as most likely it is ancient.

Comment: It is necessary that I contact my host who mean ovh? I'm at ovh

Comment: Yes it is necessary. You also need to make sure you have a host that caters to Magento as well. Don't expect to run Magento on a $5/month hosting plan. You can spend weeks just optimizing the server for Magento.

Comment: On my server there is a file (.ovhconfig) I set the php5. but when I go to my ssh it still shows me the same error

Comment: You need to do what i'm telling you to do. You are going off on your own tangent not helping yourself.

Comment: OK tomorrow I contact and I want you to know

Comment: The problem is resolved the problem came from Simple configurable product